# generate and change Gcloud API-Key via API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

We want to provide our API services through the Gcloud Endpoints. Our customers have to generate an API key in order to integrate our API into their project. 
Is there a way to generate the Gcloud api key via an interface? How can I assign rights for an api key via an Gcloud-API?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, GCP currently has no API for programmatic provisioning / access of API Keys.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Andrew, currently it’s not possible to create or manage API keys programmatic or using gcloud, but there’s a [request](https://issuetracker.google.com/76227920) to add this functionality, you can track the progress of this request or post your comments on it, but keep in mind that there's no ETA or guarantee that it will be implemented.